# npm install PDFkit fails

Tags: node.js, npm, pdfkit

I'm trying to install PDFKit for node.js using the recommended command:

```
npm install pdfkit
```

However it fails with the following messages:

> zlib@1.0.5 preinstall /home/woody/node_modules/pdfkit/node_modules/zlib
>   node-waf clean || true; node-waf configure build

```
sh: node-waf: not found
sh: node-waf: not found
npm ERR! error installing zlib@1.0.5 Error: zlib@1.0.5 preinstall: `node-waf clean || true; node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! error installing zlib@1.0.5 `sh "-c" "node-waf clean || true; node-waf configure build"` failed with 127
npm ERR! error installing zlib@1.0.5     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exec.js:49:20)
npm ERR! error installing zlib@1.0.5     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR! error installing zlib@1.0.5     at ChildProcess.onexit (child_process.js:192:12)
npm ERR! error installing pdfkit@0.1.5 Error: zlib@1.0.5 preinstall: `node-waf clean || true; node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! error installing pdfkit@0.1.5 `sh "-c" "node-waf clean || true; node-waf configure build"` failed with 127
npm ERR! error installing pdfkit@0.1.5     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exec.js:49:20)
npm ERR! error installing pdfkit@0.1.5     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR! error installing pdfkit@0.1.5     at ChildProcess.onexit (child_process.js:192:12)
npm ERR! zlib@1.0.5 preinstall: `node-waf clean || true; node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-waf clean || true; node-waf configure build"` failed with 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the zlib@1.0.5 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the zlib package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-waf clean || true; node-waf configure build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls zlib
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-33-generic-pae
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "pdfkit"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/woody/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS

If anyone has any help or suggestions, that'd be great - thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need install nodejs-dev package:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-dev
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue like  i see node-waf not found. Any idea how i can install nodejs-dev on windows 8...